# POST Request fail with Node.js and Express.js

Tags: node.js, post, express

New web dev here, coming form the land of C, and everything is a little new :)

I'm working through some Express learning, and am stuck on getting POST requests to work. I'm using Advanced Rest Client on Chrome to send a POST request and am getting errors, no error number just a simple 'computer says no'.

My app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
    , http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.json());
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello, Express!");
});

app.get("/hi", function(req, res) {
    var message = "Hello :-)";
    res.send(message);
});

app.get("/users/:userId", function(req, res) {
    res.send("<h1>Hello user #" + req.params.userId);
});

app.post("/users", function(req, res) {
    res.send("Creating a new user with name " + req.body.username);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

All the other routes work, just that POST that fails.

EDIT: Additional, I'm using text/html as the content type when I post.

I've restarted the server, ensured the file is saved, rebooted the system etc. I'm guessing the issue is the parsing of the body is failing. Any help would be great, cheers.

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are receiving on the server or as a response?

Comment: Thats the thing, it gives no error, simply says it cannot send the request. I switch clients and it's working now.

Comment: "says it cannot send the request" *is* an error, but I've never had an HTTP error show up as "computer says no". So please add the actual error you are getting. This probably requires going into the developer tools, selecting the network tab and showing us which network request is failing. It is possible to attach a screenshot to your question if you can't get an understandable textual representation that you can paste in.

Answer (score 1):

`express.json()` doesn't parse `text/html`, so you have no `req.body` inside your route handler, and `req.body.username` line will throw an error.

> I've restarted the server, ensured the file is saved, rebooted the system etc. I'm guessing the issue is the parsing of the body is failing.

Don't guess. Debug and read logs (`app.use(express.logger('dev'))`);